# How to extend tappable area to whole frame in SwiftUI (iOS14)?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make a `VGrid` with Swift 5.3, but the only tappable area is the upper part of the rectangle. Other answers suggest `contentShape`, but I am unable to make that work either. How to make the whole frame tappable? Code below:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

struct Item: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = Bundle.main.decode([Item].self, from: "data.json")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var itemID = Item.ID()
    @StateObject var userData = UserData()
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 118))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(userData.items) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ContentDetail(itemID: item.id - 1)) {
                            ContentRow(item: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentRow: View {
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ZStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        Text(item.name)
                            .font(.caption)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 120)
                .border(Color.primary, width: 2)
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentDetail: View {
    @State var itemID = Item.ID()
    @StateObject var userData = UserData()

    var body: some View {
            Text(userData.items[itemID].name)
    }
}

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String, dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate, keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy

        do {
            return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to missing key '\(key.stringValue)' not found – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to type mismatch – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let type, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to missing \(type) value – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(_) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle because it appears to be invalid JSON")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And the JSON part:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Example data",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Example data 2",
    }
]
```

Any help is appreciated. Could this be a bug in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply remove the GeometryReader since you set the height anyway:

```
struct ContentRow: View {
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    Text(item.name)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
            .border(Color.primary, width: 2)
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up setting only the height, I guess grid view takes care of the width. Is this a GeometryReader bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the contentShape on the outermost VStack of ContentRow. You need to put the contentShape on the view that is *expanding* to fill its parent (or on its parent), which in your case I think is the GeometryReader. The views inside the GeometryReader all shrink to fit their contents, so your contentShape rectangle doesn’t help there.